# Can't access old iTunes purchases after changing email address

Tags: itunes, email

I made my account around 2006, and have changed my email address a couple of times. Now I can't download past purchases or even listen to the songs I purchased without my iPad prompting me to enter my old address and password for those songs.

When I went onto the Apple website and put "forgot password" for my "old accounts", of course it told me that those accounts did not exist. Of course they didn't, because they were never separate accounts like Apple claims.

What can I do about this?

Comment: Isn't contacting Apple support the best thing to do here? What are you trying to accomplish by asking us here who don't have access to Apple's records. See [Why we're not Customer Support for Apple](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like something is broken on the iTunes side - you can indeed change your email address and it's all still tied to the same Apple "account", meaning all your old purchases should still be there.

The very first thing you should do is [contact iTunes support](https://getsupport.apple.com/Issues.action) and explain what happened. Chances are high they'll be able to correct whatever's happened.